# How to format multiple 'if else' statements into "public static void" methods in selenium java project

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber

I have a java code with lots of IF Else statements in a single method. Below is the sample one.
How do i convert them into individual methods, I need to refactor those IF Else statements into Methods, and I have to use these refactored methods in my StepDefinition in Cucumber-Selenium framework.

Can someone please help me with this...

```
else if(action.equals("Load"))
{
Reporter.log(description+"|"+data);
driver.get(data);
if(!TestBase.browserName.equals("Chrome"))
{
driver.manage().window().maximize();
screenSize=driver.manage().window().getSize().toString();
System.out.println("My screensize is "+screenSize);
}

}else if(action.equals("RefreshPage"))
{
driver.navigate().refresh();                         
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(                        
By.xpath("//span[contains(text(),'salesforce.com, inc. All rights 
reserved.')]")));
}

else if(action.equals("InsertData"))
{
Reporter.log(description+"|"+data);
moveToElement(elementReference, referenceValue);
findElement(elementReference, referenceValue).click();
findElement(elementReference, referenceValue).clear();

if (description.toLowerCase().contains("request name")||                         
referenceValue.contains("reqNme")){
String customNum=getDate("requestName");
findElement(elementReference, referenceValue).sendKeys(data+customNum);
System.out.println("Request Name is "+data+customNum);
} else {
findElement(elementReference, referenceValue).sendKeys(data);
}
}
else if(action.equals("uploadFile"))
{
File file = new File(data);
String filePath=file.getAbsolutePath();
System.out.println(filePath);
findElement(elementReference, referenceValue).clear();
findElement(elementReference, referenceValue).sendKeys(filePath);
}
else if(action.equals("uploadImage"))
{
Reporter.log(description+"||"+data);
uploadImage(elementReference, referenceValue, "Logo", new File(data));
}
else if(action.equals("waitElVisibility"))
{
wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,Long.parseLong(data));
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(findElement(elementReference, 
referenceValue)));
}
else if(action.equals("waitElInVisibility"))
{
wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,Long.parseLong(data));
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(
By.xpath(referenceValue)));
}
```

I have to create a method for those If Else statements - 
Load
RefreshPage
InsertData
uploadFile
waitElVisibility
waitElInVisibility

Comment: Have answered your question, please check and let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make separate methods in the class for every else if condition so that if going forward you need those actions to be performed again, you can directly use the method and perform the action. I am using private access modifier now but you can make it public if you want to use that method outside the class as well. And instead of using else if, you should use switch, so that in future if any other action comes into play, so just need to add that in the switch condition.

Your code should look something like:

```
 public class ActionClass{

 // Making all methods for the actions you need to perform
 private static void loadData(){
    Reporter.log(description+"|"+data);
    driver.get(data);
    if(!TestBase.browserName.equals("Chrome"))
    {
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    screenSize=driver.manage().window().getSize().toString();
    System.out.println("My screensize is "+screenSize);
    }       
}

private static void refreshPage(){
    driver.navigate().refresh();                         
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(                        
    By.xpath("//span[contains(text(),'salesforce.com, inc. All rights 
    reserved.')]")));
}


private static void insertData(){
    Reporter.log(description+"|"+data);
    moveToElement(elementReference, referenceValue);
    findElement(elementReference, referenceValue).click();
    findElement(elementReference, referenceValue).clear();

    if (description.toLowerCase().contains("request name")||                         
    referenceValue.contains("reqNme")){
    String customNum=getDate("requestName");
    findElement(elementReference, referenceValue).sendKeys(data+customNum);
    System.out.println("Request Name is "+data+customNum);
    } else {
    findElement(elementReference, referenceValue).sendKeys(data);
    }
}


private static void uploadFile(){
    File file = new File(data);
    String filePath=file.getAbsolutePath();
    System.out.println(filePath);
    findElement(elementReference, referenceValue).clear();
    findElement(elementReference, referenceValue).sendKeys(filePath);
}

private static void uploadImageAction(){
    Reporter.log(description+"||"+data);
    uploadImage(elementReference, referenceValue, "Logo", new File(data));

}

private static void waitElVisibility(){
    wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,Long.parseLong(data));
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(findElement(elementReference, 
    referenceValue)));

}

private static void waitElInvisibility(){
    wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,Long.parseLong(data));
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(
    By.xpath(referenceValue)));

}

// The main method where switch condition will be present
    public static void main(String[] args) {
// Initialise the action string according to your code
    String action = null;
    switch (action) {
    case ("Load"):
        loadData();
        break;
    case ("RefreshPage"):
        refreshPage();
        break;

    case ("InsertData"):
        insertData();
        break;

    case ("uploadFile"):
        uploadFile();
        break;

    case ("uploadImage"):
        uploadImageAction();
        break;

    case ("waitElVisibility"):
        waitElVisibility();
        break;

    case ("waitElInVisibility"):
        waitElInvisibility();
        break;

    default:
        System.out.println("Action did not match");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Happy to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can split if-else blocks contents into multiple methods and if you want to get rid of if-else then the alternative is, you can use the switch statement. See the code below :

```
public class PublicStaticVoids {

    private static WebDriver driver;
    private static WebDriverWait wait;

    private static void loadThePage(String description, String data) {
        Reporter.log(description+"|"+data);
        driver.get(data); // Initialize the driver before doing this
        if(!TestBase.browserName.equals("Chrome"))
        {
            driver.manage().window().maximize();
            String screenSize = driver.manage().window().getSize().toString();
            System.out.println("My screensize is "+screenSize);
        }
    }

    private static void refreshThePage(String description, String data, WebElement elementReference, String referenceValue) {
        Reporter.log(description+"|"+data);
        moveToElement(elementReference, referenceValue);
        findElement(elementReference, referenceValue).click();
        findElement(elementReference, referenceValue).clear();

        if (description.toLowerCase().contains("request name")||                         
                referenceValue.contains("reqNme")){
            String customNum = getDate("requestName");
            findElement(elementReference, referenceValue).sendKeys(data+customNum);
            System.out.println("Request Name is "+data+customNum);
        } else {
            findElement(elementReference, referenceValue).sendKeys(data);
        }
    }

    private static void uploadTheFile(String data, WebElement elementReference, String referenceValue) {
        File file = new File(data);
        String filePath=file.getAbsolutePath();
        System.out.println(filePath);
        findElement(elementReference, referenceValue).clear();
        findElement(elementReference, referenceValue).sendKeys(filePath);
    }

    private static void uploadTheImage(String description, String data, WebElement elementReference, String referenceValue) {
        Reporter.log(description+"||"+data);
        uploadImage(elementReference, referenceValue, "Logo", new File(data));
    }

    private static void waitForVisibility(String data, WebElement elementReference, String referenceValue) {
        wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,Long.parseLong(data));
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(findElement(elementReference, referenceValue)));
    }

    private static void waitForInVisibility(String data, String referenceValue) {
        wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,Long.parseLong(data));
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(referenceValue)));
    }

    public static void main(String... ali) {
        String action = "some action";
        switch(action) {
        case "Load":
            loadThePage("some description", "some data");
            break;
        case "RefreshPage":
            refreshThePage("description", "data", "someValue", "someValue"));
            break;
        case "uploadFile":
            uploadTheFile("someData", "someReference", "some value");
            break;
        case "uploadImage":
            uploadTheImage("description", "data", "Some Reference", "some value");
            break;
        case "waitELVisibility":
            waitForVisibility("data", "some ref", "some value");
            break;
        case "waitElInvisibility":
            waitForInvisibility("data", "some value");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

You can re-use these methods whenever you want to by passing values are parameters. If you don't want to pass values as parameters then remove it and then declare & initialize those 
variables with static keyword on above the methods and you can use it inside of method later.

Below is the corresponding if-else conditions for the above switch-case statements :

```
if(action.equals("Load"))
{
    loadThePage("some description", "some data");
}
else if(action.equals("RefreshPage"))
{
    refreshThePage("description", "data", "someValue", "someValue"));
}
else if(action.equals("uploadFile"))
{
    uploadTheFile("someData", "someReference", "some value");
}
else if(action.equals("uploadImage"))
{
    uploadTheImage("description", "data", "Some Reference", "some value");
}
else if(action.equals("waitELVisibility"))
{
    waitForVisibility("data", "some ref", "some value");
}
else if(action.equals("waitElInvisibility"))
{
    waitForInvisibility("data", "some value");
}
```

I hope it helps...

Comment: appreciate your help, yes I will construct methods the same way as you mentioned

Answer (score -1):

In general I wouldn't use static methods. For sake of the example I made them static and assume that all objects are accessible(all class variables). Also I did not implement all methods - only schematic:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    //...

    // i would use a switch for the dispatch
    switch(action){
      case "Load": handleLoad(); break;
      case "RefreshPage": handeRefreshPage(); break;
      case "InsertData" : insertData(); break;
      // ...
    }

    //...
}

// define the handlers for the actions as individual methods:

public static void handleLoad(){
    Reporter.log(description+"|"+data);
    driver.get(data);
    if(!TestBase.browserName.equals("Chrome")){
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        screenSize=driver.manage().window().getSize().toString();
        System.out.println("My screensize is "+screenSize);
    }

}

public static void handleRefreshPage(){
    driver.navigate().refresh();                         
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(                        
    By.xpath("//span[contains(text(),'salesforce.com, inc. All rights reserved.')]")));  
}

// and so on
```

Comment: Thank you Kai for your help!